# Fortran 77: How to use array output from function or subroutine

Tags: arrays, matrix, fortran, fortran77

I've only been learning Fortran 77 (and its syntax) the last few days, and tried finding answers throughout the site and textbooks already and come up still confused, so I'd appreciate any help. I'm sorry if the formatting on this post is off; this is my first post, and I'm crunched for time.

I'm creating a program to multiply matrices. I want to create a subroutine or a function that will take two matrices as inputs (two 2x2 arrays), and return the multiplied matrix (one 2x2 array). I can't figure out how to get either a subroutine or a function to return an array of fixed size, or how to use the array once it's returned.

I tried using a function, which compiled on its own. But when I tried calling the function from my main program, I couldn't call it on its own:

> ```
>  MATMULT(MAT0, MAT0, MAT0)                                        
>  1
>  Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
> ```

or assign it to another variable (I tried different REALs and arrays):

> ```
>   BLAH = MATMULT(MAT0, MAT0, MAT0)                                 
>                 1
>   Error: Return type mismatch of function 'matmult' at (1) (INTEGER(4)/REAL(4))
>   MATRIX1.f:26.22:
>
>   BLAH = MATMULT(MAT0, MAT0, MAT0)                                 
>                  1
>   Warning: Type mismatch in argument 'x' at (1); passed INTEGER(4) to REAL(4)
>
>   BLAH = MATMULT(MAT0, MAT0, MAT0)                                 
>                  1
>   Warning: Rank mismatch in argument 'x' at (1) (scalar and rank-2)
> ```

Since arrays are passed by reference, I'm really not sure what the function is returning, so how can I use the output matrix, if that is indeed the function's output?

I also tried using a subroutine, but (in addition to still not knowing what it's returning or where) then I get a "Two main PROGRAMs" error - so the compiler isn't differentiating between the main program and the subroutine. This might be a problem with my syntax on subroutines? I tried a few different things, but here's my most recent iteration of the code (I'm just trying to get the array-passing to work, so there's not actual matrix multiplication in here yet):

> ```
>   PROGRAM MATRIX1
>
>   INTEGER N 
>   REAL A, B, MAT0(2,2), MATF(2,2), X(2,2), Y(2,2), Z(2,2)
>   REAL BLAH
>
>
>   PRINT *, " ENTER THE VALUE OF A: "
>   READ *, A
>   PRINT *, " ENTER THE VALUE OF B: "
>   READ *, B
>   PRINT *, " ENTER THE NUMBER OF MULTIPLICATIONS: "
>   READ *, N
> ```
>
> C      Creates the initial matrix
>         MAT0(1,1) = 1.0 - A
>         MAT0(1,2) = A
>         MAT0(2,1) = B
>         MAT0(2,2) = 1.0 - B
>
> ```
>   PRINT *, "M = ", MAT0
>
>   CALL MATMULT(MAT0, MAT0, MAT0)
>   PRINT *, "FINAL "
>
>
>   STOP
>   END PROGRAM
>
>   REAL SUBBROUTINE MATMULT(X, Y, Z)
>
>       END SUBROUTINE
> ```

Or (edited to add some of the recommended changes) with a function:

> ```
>   PROGRAM MATRIX1
>
>   INTEGER N 
>   REAL A, B, MAT0(2,2), MATF(2,2), X(2,2), Y(2,2), Z(2,2)
>   REAL MATMULT(2,2)
>
>
>   PRINT *, " ENTER THE VALUE OF A: "
>   READ *, A
>   PRINT *, " ENTER THE VALUE OF B: "
>   READ *, B
>   PRINT *, " ENTER THE NUMBER OF MULTIPLICATIONS: "
>   READ *, N
> ```
>
> C      Creates the initial matrix
>         MAT0(1,1) = 1.0 - A
>         MAT0(1,2) = A
>         MAT0(2,1) = B
>         MAT0(2,2) = 1.0 - B
>
> ```
>   PRINT *, "M = ", MAT0
>
>   Z = MATMULT(X, Y)
>
>
>   STOP
>   END PROGRAM
>
>   FUNCTION MATMULT(X, Y)
>       REAL X(2,2), Y(2,2), Z(2,2), MATMULT(2,2)
>       RETURN
>       END
> ```

I'm still getting errors:

> ```
>   Z = MATMULT(X, Y)                                                
>               1
>   Warning: Legacy Extension: REAL array index at (1)
>   MATRIX1.f:28.19:
>
>   Z = MATMULT(X, Y)                                                
>               1
>   Error: Array index at (1) is an array of rank 2
> ```

Comment: There are several issues you raise here, but I can't match most of the errors with the code sample you provide.

Comment: I'm going to guess you really don't mean to restrict yourself to Fortran77.  You cant return an array with f77 and the fact you aren't getting an error about that indicates you are already using a compiler from this century. You should edit your tags and subject ..

Answer (score 1):

In this era there is no reason for use FORTRAN 77.  Fortran 90/95/2003 is easier to use, more powerful, and better assists the programer in finding mistakes.  gfortran is an excellent open-source compiler.

Here is an example in Fortran 95 of a similar program/function: a function that implements a vector-cross product.  The example shows the function and program in the same file (there are other approaches) with the function receiving two vectors and returning one vector.  Example: [Computing the cross product of two vectors in Fortran 90](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511711/computing-the-cross-product-of-two-vectors-in-fortran-90)

Comment: Thank you, that's what I've been hearing. I'm using a gfortran compiler, but unfortunately I've been assigned to use Fortran77, so I don't have any choice...Thanks for the link :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this:

1) Subroutine. Declare a subroutine like you did. However, specify input and output parameters:

```
REAL, INTENT(IN) :: X(2,2), Y(2,2)
REAL, INTENT(OUT) :: Z(2,2)
```

and call the subroutine using `call` keyword: `CALL MATMULT`

2) Function. Also specify input parameter, but now return value of the function:

```
! Insert calculation
MALMULT = ...
```

Don't forget to declare it in proper way: `FUNCTION MATMULT(x,Y)`

Call it: `Z = MATMULT(X,Y)`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I still have the same problem when calling the function MATMULT. How would you call it? If I try MATMULT = MATMULT(X,Y,Z) or MAT = MATMULT(X,Y,Z), or just MATMULT(X,Y,Z) I get the Error: Unclassifiable statement. The function is defined, it's just using the output after calling the function that's not working.

Comment: I think you mean [`intent`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fortran/Fortran_procedures_and_functions#Intent) and not `intend`.

Comment: Don't forget you must have an explicit interface to return the array (Contains or Module).

Answer (score 0):

You mention several problems in your question.  Certainly your work will be enhanced using more recent Fortran dialects, as given in the answers by M. S. B. and Ilmirus.  And you really should be using `implicit none` (even for Fortran 77 a lot of compilers support that - and lower case - as an extension).

Coming to the conceptual part, I must say that you need to continue your learning.  However, if you want a function which *returns* the matrix product then you will have something like

```
function matmult(x, y)
  real x(2,2), z(2,2), matmult(2,2)
  ... calculation of matmult
end function matmult
```

Followed by

```
z = matmult(x,y)
```

in the main program, where `z` is `real z(2,2)`, rather than the scalar `blah` you have in your example, and is your result.

Coming to your subroutine, there are indeed problems: `real subroutine matmult(x,y,z)` requires not the `real`.  Then calling this with `call matmult(mat0, mat0, mat0)` where you intend to update `mat0` with a result is asking for aliasing problems.  `call matmult(x,y,z)` will "store the result" where the subroutine calculations put it.  Using `intent` as given by Ilmirus is a good guide to the behaviour desired by the programmer.

Finally, if you just want to get the result of multiplying `A` and `B` as matrices and storing in `C`: use `C = matmul(A,B)` with a later-than-F77 compiler.

However, in Fortran 77 one doesn't return array results, so the subroutine approach is the one to go for.  In response to your edit:

```
  REAL MATMULT(2,2)
```

is declaring `matmult` an array, not a function, so references to `matmult(X,Y)` give rise to your error.