# Unclassifiable statement in Fortran 95 when declaring function

Tags: fortran

I would appreciate some help on this.  The point of the program is to take a lower bound, an upper bound, and the number of steps, and then input them into the respective chosen equation to create a matrix that is the length of the steps, that contains the values for for the equation that was chosen. I'm getting an unclassifiable statement at:

```
array(i)=function1(x)
array(i)=function2(x)
array(i)=function3(x)
```

I feel like it has something to do with how I declared my function, but I cannot figure out a fix to it.  Any help would be appreciated.

> ```
>   PROGRAM stuff1
>     IMPLICIT NONE
>
>     !variables
>       INTEGER::i,step
>       REAL::lower,upper,function1,function2,function3,x,q,w,e
>       CHARACTER(20)::option
>       REAL,ALLOCATABLE::array(:)
>
>     !formats
>     101 FORMAT(A)     !single text element only
>     102 FORMAT()      ! <description>
>
>     !-------Variable Definitions-------!
>     !
>     !
>     !
>     !----------------------------------!
>
>     !x= .1(upper-lower)
>
>     !<Begin Coding Here>
>
>     WRITE(*,101)"Hello User, please select a function to evaluate:"
>     WRITE(*,101)
>     WRITE(*,101)"A) f(x)=x^2+2x+4"
>     WRITE(*,101)"B) f(x)=|x+4|"
>     WRITE(*,101)"C) f(x)=sin(x)+42"
>     WRITE(*,101)"Enter A,B,or C"
>
>       DO
>       READ(*,101)option
>       IF ((option.EQ."A") .OR. (option.EQ."a")) THEN
>       ELSE IF((option.EQ.'B') .OR. (option.EQ.'b'))THEN
>       ELSE IF((option.EQ.'c') .OR. (option.EQ.'c'))THEN
>       ELSE 
>       WRITE(*,*)"Please enter A,B,or C"
>       CYCLE
>       END IF
>       EXIT
>       END DO
>
>     WRITE(*,101)"please enter an lower bound:"
>
>       READ(*,*)lower
>
>     WRITE(*,101)
>     WRITE(*,101)"please enter an upper bound:"
>       READ(*,*)upper
>
>     WRITE(*,101)
>     WRITE(*,101)"please enter a step size"
>       READ(*,*)step
>
>
>     function1=((x**2)+(2*x)+4)
>     function2=(abs(x+4))
>     function3=(sin(x)+42)
>
>
>     ALLOCATE(array(step))
>     x=lower
>     DO i=1,step
>       IF ((option.EQ."A") .OR. (option.EQ."a")) THEN
>           array(i)=function1(x)
>       ELSE IF((option.EQ.'B') .OR. (option.EQ.'b'))THEN
>           array(i)=function2(x)
>       ELSE IF((option.EQ.'c') .OR. (option.EQ.'c'))THEN
>           array(i)=function3(x)
>       END IF
>       x=x+(upper-lower)/step
>     END DO
>
>     DO i=1,step
>       WRITE(*,'(4F6.2)')array(i)
>     END DO
>
>     END PROGRAM
> ```

Answer (score 4):

These lines

```
function1=((x**2)+(2*x)+4)
function2=(abs(x+4))
function3=(sin(x)+42)
```

appear to be three *statement functions*.  This is an obsolescent feature which you should not use, instead you should define functions along the lines

```
   real function one(x)
       real, intent(in) :: x
       one = x**2 + 2*x + 4
   end function one
```

If you must program like it's 1979 then the correct form for a statement function would be

```
function1(x)=((x**2)+(2*x)+4)
```

You have omitted the dummy argument in the definitions, it's no surprise to me that the compiler gets angry and issues that error.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how to define a function in Fortran!

After the `END PROGRAM`, define your functions like:

```
real function function1(x)
  real,intent(in) :: x
  function1=((x**2)+(2*x)+4)
end function
real function function2(x)
  real,intent(in) :: x
  function2=(abs(x+4))
end function
real function function3(x)
  real,intent(in) :: x
  function3=(sin(x)+42)
end function
```

Or, even better, put them into a module!

Comment: Example of how to arrange module, subroutine or function and main program: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511711/computing-the-cross-product-of-two-vectors-in-fortran-90

Comment: I would say the most straightforward alternative of a statement function is an internal function.

Comment: @VladimirF I agree, but that would require additional changes to the code given by the OP.

Comment: For clarity I suggest the syntax "end function foo" rather than just "end function" as used in the code above.

Comment: I do not, the functions are very short, you can look for the name two lines above. It is a pain to rename a function and then forget to rename the `end function`, so I recommend to use the name there only if the function does not fit a single screen.