# Unclassifiable statement at (1) and Unexpected data declaration statement at (1) in Fortran77?

Tags: file, count, fortran, gfortran, fortran77

I am trying to count the number of lines in a file in Fortran 77
(My file has two columns, both with numbers)

I am getting an unclassifiable statement and unexpected data declaration and I am not sure why. This is my code: (new to fortran 77):

```
    PROGRAM Exercise

C
C John Smith
C

C
C PARAMETERS
C
      REAL PRECISION UNUM
      PARAMETER (UNUM=15)
C
C LOCAL VARIABLES
C

C
C FUNCTION DECLARATIONS
C

      INTEGER*8 PRECISION NUMLIN

C
C COMMON VARIABLES
C

C
C DATA STATEMENTS
C
      DATA FILEN /'linecounttester.txt'/
C
C MAIN PROGRAM MODULE
C

      OPEN(UNIT=UNUM, FILE = FILEN, STATUS='OLD')

C
C function counts the lines in the file

C

      FUNCTION NUMLIN
      INTEGER*8 PRECISION NUMLIN
      CHARACTER*256 LINE
      100 READ(UNUM,*,END=200) LINE
      NUMLIN=NUMLIN+1
      GOTO 100
      200 CONTINUE

      RETURN
      END

      REWIND(UNUM)

      CLOSE(UNUM)
```

This is my data file: (just a tester so I can count the lines to 8): 
1   100
2   200
3   300
4   400
5   500
6   600
7   700
8   800

These are my errors:

Exercise.for:58.6:

```
  FUNCTION NUMLIN                                                   
  1
```

Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
Exercise.for:59.32:

```
  INTEGER*8 PRECISION NUMLIN                                        
                            1
```

Error: Symbol 'precisionnumlin' at (1) already has basic type of INTEGER
Exercise.for:60.72:

```
  CHARACTER*256 LINE                                                
                                                                    1
```

Error: Unexpected data declaration statement at (1)
Exercise.for:61.7:

```
  100 READ(UNUM,*,END=200)                                          
   1
```

Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
Exercise.for:62.6:

```
  LINE                                                              
  1
```

Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
Exercise.for:65.7:

```
  200 CONTINUE                                                      
   1
```

Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
Exercise.for:41.10:

```
  DATA FILEN /'linecounttester.txt'/                                
      1
```

Error: Incompatible types in DATA statement at (1); attempted conversion of CHARACTER(1) to REAL(4)
Exercise.for:46.16:

```
  OPEN(UNIT=UNUM, FILE = FILEN, STATUS='OLD')                       
            1
```

Error: UNIT tag at (1) must be of type INTEGER
Exercise.for:64.72:

```
  GOTO 100                                                          
                                                                    1
```

Error: Label 100 referenced at (1) is never defined
Exercise.for:1.72:

```
  PROGRAM EXERCISE                                    
                                                                    1
```

Exercise.for:70.72:

```
  REWIND(UNUM)                                                      
                                                                    2
```

Error: Two main PROGRAMs at (1) and (2)

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Personally I no longer help people write FORTRAN77. It's rather like helping people amputate limbs quickly without anaesthetic.  And for much the same reason: there are more modern approaches which are much less painful for all concerned.  If I were trying to help, my first step would be to question why you report errors in lines (*eg* `PROGRAM NUMBERCOUNTINGEXERCSIE`) which do not appear in thecode you have posted.

Comment: I'll be pedantic and say that this source is not FORTRAN 77. INTEGER*8 is non-standard. Also, "REAL PRECISION UNUM" possibly doesn't mean what you think it is. I agree with HPM that the messages don't seem to match the source.

Comment: is that `PRECISION` maybe some legacy extension? Certainly not f77.

Comment: REAL PRECISION the data type?

Comment: right there is no such data type in standard fortran (of any vintage). Your compiler thinks you are declaring a `REAL`variable named `PRECISIONUNUM`  (note spaces are not significant in fortran).

Comment: Having `function` inside a main program without a contains is confusing the compiler.  The order of your statements is wrong.  For an example of how to arrange a function or subroutine and a main program in Fortran >=90, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511711/computing-the-cross-product-of-two-vectors-in-fortran-90

Comment: This is Fortran77; I assume this is still applicable?

Comment: Why are you writing Fortran 77 in 2013?  The statement order is a problem in any version of Fortran.   The example layout is Fortran >=90.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing your namespaces.

you have a

```
PROGRAM
```

statement, which needs a corresponding

```
END
```

statement before you start declaring your functions.

that should fix the compilation errors you see. however, i do not see where you actually call the function you create. in other words, it appears that you are defining a function without actually using it. I would suggest that you first write the code without the function, just to make sure it works. then separate it out, until you get the hang of this :)

EDIT: I also second the comments under your question, about the strange syntax you are using. though I will not dissuade you from using FORTRAN77 but i hope you have a very good reason to do so ;)