# Fortran, 'dim' argument of 'size' intrinsic is not a valid dimension index

Tags: matrix, multidimensional-array, size, fortran, fortran90

I'm new to Fortran.
For now, I'm trying to make a simple function that should print the coefficients of a matrix.
Originally I wanted to do something more interesting with the matrix (that's why I used the FUNCTION keyword), but I had to dumb it down, since "Hello world", and "multiply a number by 2" are the only programs I managed to compile so far.

Here is my code:

```
PROGRAM my_program
    IMPLICIT NONE
    INTEGER, EXTERNAL :: print_coefs
END PROGRAM my_program

FUNCTION print_coefs(arr)
    IMPLICIT NONE
    REAL, INTENT(IN), DIMENSION(:) :: arr
    INTEGER :: print_coefs
    INTEGER :: i,j
    do i = 1, size(arr, 1)
        do j = 1, size(arr, 2)
            print *, arr(i,j)
        enddo
    enddo
    print_coefs = 0
END FUNCTION
```

So I have this error at compile time:

Error: 'dim' argument of 'size' intrinsic at (1) is not a valid dimension index.

Why? Isn't `size` the right way to get the dimensions of the matrix?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array `arr` is declared as being of rank 1.  So, assuming the compiler is pointing to the line where `size(arr,2)` is given, this is not valid code: it is asking for the size of the second (non-existent) dimension.

From the rest of the function `print_coeffs` it appears desirable that `arr` be declared as rank-2: `real, intent(in), dimension(:,:) :: arr`.

It should, however, be noted that a function like this (`arr` is an *assumed-shape array*) will require an explicit interface for the caller.  That is, if you want to call this function eventually from the main program then `integer, external :: print_coeffs` isn't going to be sufficient.  See other questions and answers on SO---such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6511711/3157076)---for more details.

Comment: Thanks! I thought `:` in `dimension(:)` was a separator and in fact it's a placeholder!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511711/computing-the-cross-product-of-two-vectors-in-fortran-90 for an example of how to organize your subprogram into a module so that the interface is automatically known to the caller.