# Fortran array cannot be returned in function: not a DUMMY variable

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran

Being new to Fortran 90 free-form, I would really like to know why the following piece of code snippet would not work:

```
program test2
    implicit none
    !!! A program to practice f90 writing.
    ! Define double precision data
    integer, parameter :: dp = kind(1.d0)
    real(dp) :: a(3), b(3)
    integer :: i
    a = (/(i, i=1, 3)/)
    b = (/(i, i=1, 3)/)
    write (*, *) m31tensorprod(a, b)

contains
    function m31tensorprod(a, b)
        real(dp), dimension(3), intent(in) :: a, b
        real(dp), intent(out) :: m31tensorprod(3, 3)
        integer :: k1, k2
        forall(k1=1:3, k2=1:3)
            m31tensorprod(k1, k2) = a(k1) * b(k2)
        end forall
        return
    end function m31tensorprod
end program test2
```

When I try to compile this via gfortran test2.f90, it says:

> test2.f90:13.4:
>
> ```
> function m31tensorprod(a, b)
> 1 Error: Symbol at (1) is not a DUMMY variable
> ```

I thought because `m31tensorprod` is an internal function, it shouldn't need to be declared. Where did I do wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: `intent(out)` is inappropriate for the result.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/24170024/3157076 for more (among other) detail.

Comment: @francescalus Thank you for your response! I went to the referenced question. Does that mean: for the variable `function_name`, it does not have an allocated address in the memory yet, so it is not a dummy variable pointing to the address of the output. Therefore, `intent(out)` would be illegal. Is that right?

Comment: "Dummy" just means the arguments to the function.  In this case `a` and `b` _in_ the function.  Intent can be specified for dummy variables only.

Comment: @francescalus Oh OK! "Intent can be specified for the function arguments only". That totally explained it. Thanks a lot! Would you like to post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are correct that `m31tensorprod` being an internal function means that you do not have to declare it in the main program.  In the jargon: it has an explicit interface.

However, that is not the problem with your code.  What is going wrong is with the function definition itself.  [Admittedly the compiler message isn't too helpful.]

The definition of the function subprogram

```
function m31tensorprod(a, b)
```

defines a function with *result variable* `m31tensorprod`.  This result variable is subject to your declaration

```
    real(dp), intent(out) :: m31tensorprod(3, 3)
```

It is this declaration which is incorrect.  You may declare type (`real(dp)`) and dimension (`(3,3)`) but the `intent(out)` is erroneous.

The `intent` attribute, in the words of the [Fortran standard](http://www.j3-fortran.org/doc/year/10/10-007.pdf), is subject to the constraint (C538)

> An entity with the INTENT attribute shall be a dummy data object or a dummy procedure pointer.

Coming back to the compiler message, `m31tensorprod` is not a dummy variable.  In this case the dummy arguments are `a` and `b`.  In general the dummy arguments are those things between the `(` and the `)`,